# JPA OneToMany, ManyToOne bidirectional

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to get rid of the following error:

> The attribute [lcritical] in entity
>   class [class
>   pl.pwc.docs.pl704.PL704_Error] has a
>   mappedBy value of [pl704_error] which
>   does not exist in its owning entity
>   class [class
>   pl.pwc.docs.pl704.PL704_Error_Critical].
>   If the owning entity class is a
>   @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid,
>   and your attribute should reference
>   the correct subclass.

**PL704 @Entity class:**

```
@Entity  
public class PL704 implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;  
    private int Status;  
    private String Comments;  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pl704", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=PL704_Error.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
    private Collection lerror = new ArrayList<PL704_Error>();

    //getters, setters...
```

**PL704_Error @Entity class:**

```
@Entity  
public class PL704_Error implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;  
    private String ErrorType;  
    private String ErrorReason;  
    private String ErrorLocation;  
    private String OriginalAttributeValue;  
    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name = "PL704_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")  
    private PL704 pl704;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pl704_error", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,     targetEntity=PL704_Error_Critical.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
    private Collection lcritical = new ArrayList<PL704_Error_Critical>();

    //getters, setters...
```

**PL704_Error_Critical @Entity class:**

```
@Entity  
public class PL704_Error_Critical implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;  
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinColumn(name = "PL704_ERROR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")  
    private PL704_Error error;  

    //getters, setters...
```

Summing up, One `PL704` can have many `PL704_Error`. One `PL704_Error` can have many `PL704_Error_Critical`.

How should I change my code to fix an error?

Used: EclipseLink 2.1.1, H2 Embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapped by attribute spelling is not correct, maybe this is the cause:

In class PL704_Error the lcritical attribute is reversed mappedBy Attribute

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pl704_error"...
```

But the variable in PL704_Error_Critical is called only `error`.

Comment: OK, but now I have something strange: "Exception Description: [class pl.pwc.docs.pl704.PL704_Error] uses a non-entity [class pl.pwc.docs.pl704.PL704_Error_Critical] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field lcritical]."

Comment: Nothing changed, after 5 minutes it magically have started working.

Comment: still having exception above.

Comment: @monczek: Did you ever resolve the above exception?  I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="error", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
    targetEntity=PL704_Error_Critical.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection lcritical = new ArrayList<PL704_Error_Critical>();
```

look at the corresponding property name in `PL704_Error_Critical`:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PL704_ERROR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")       
private PL704_Error error;
```